# Python Data Insert From Beautiful Soup Table to MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql, csv, beautifulsoup

I am trying to insert data into a MYSQL table from a html table using beautiful soup written in python. Currently I was able to do this by creating an interim csv file but it does not seems to work in Linux and seems inefficient. Below is my code that works with the CSV, which is the portion I will like to elimnate.

```
import urllib2, base64, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
request = urllib2.Request("http://website.com")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('username','password')).replace('\n','')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.read())

table=soup.findAll('table')[6]

f = open('output.csv', 'w')

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    #For each "tr", assign each "td" to a variable.
    if len(cells) == 19:
    column1 = cells[0].find(text=True)
    column2 = cells[1].find(text=True)
    column3 = cells[2].find(text=True)
    column4 = cells[3].find(text=True)
    column5 = cells[4].find(text=True)
    column6 = cells[5].find(text=True)
    column7 = cells[6].find(text=True)
    column8 = cells[7].find(text=True)
    column9 = cells[8].find(text=True)
    column10 = cells[9].find(text=True)
    column11 = cells[10].find(text=True)
    column12 = cells[11].find(text=True)
    column13 = cells[12].find(text=True)
    column14 = cells[13].find(text=True)
    column15 = cells[14].find(text=True)
    column16 = cells[15].find(text=True)
    column17 = cells[16].find(text=True)
    column18 = cells[17].find(text=True)
    column19 = cells[18].find(text=True)
    TOTAL_AD_CALLS = column6.replace(',','')
    TOTAL_US_AD_CALLS = column7.replace(',','')
    TOTAL_NON_US_AD_CALLS = column8.replace(',','')
    TOTAL_NON_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS = column10.replace(',','')
    TOTAL_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS = column12.replace(',','')
    UNUSABLE_AD_CALLS = column13.replace(',','')
    NO_ADS_RETURNED = column14.replace(',','')
    PSAS_RETURNED = column15.replace(',','')
    ADS_RETURNED = column16.replace(',','')
    TOTAL_RETURNED = column17.replace(',','')
    TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS  = column18.replace(',','')
    Engagements = column19.replace(',','')
    NOT_US_RATE = column9.replace('%','')
    NOT_CLEAN_RATE = column11.replace('%','')



#district can be a list of lists, so we want to iterate through the top level lists first...

            write_to_file = column1 + "," + column2 + "," + column3 + "," + column4 + "," + column5 + "," + TOTAL_AD_CALLS + "," + TOTAL_US_AD_CALLS + "," + TOTAL_NON_US_AD_CALLS + "," + NOT_US_RATE + "," + TOTAL_NON_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS + "," + NOT_CLEAN_RATE + "," + TOTAL_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS + "," + UNUSABLE_AD_CALLS + "," + NO_ADS_RETURNED + "," + PSAS_RETURNED + "," + ADS_RETURNED + "," + TOTAL_RETURNED + "," +  TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS  + "," +  Engagements + "\n"
            print write_to_file
            f.write(write_to_file)
f.close()



import MySQLdb
import os
import string

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="ipadress", # your host, usually localhost
                 user="admin", # your username
                  passwd="other", # your password
                  db="dailies") # name of the data base

cursor=db.cursor()

#Query under testing
sql = """LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'output.csv' \
      INTO TABLE PYTHON_TEST \
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \
      OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  \
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' \
      IGNORE 0 LINES;;"""

  #LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' \

try:
    # Execute the SQL command
    cursor.execute(sql)
    # Commit your changes in the database
    db.commit()
except:
   # Rollback in case there is any error
   db.rollback()

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```

Comment: Sorry, what is the question/problem?

Comment: How can I bypass the CSV and insert data directly into the MYSQL table? Sorry for the confusion there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. If anyone else as a similar problem hope this helps.

```
import urllib2, base64, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import MySQLdb
import os
import string
import datetime

request = urllib2.Request("website.com")
base64string = base64.encodestring('%s:%s' % ('username','password')).replace('\n', '')
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.read())

#print(soup.prettify())
#table=soup.find('table', {"class":"resultsTable,ruler,sortable"})[0]


# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="ipaddress", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="username", # your username
                      passwd="password", # your password
                      db="databsae") # name of the data base

cursor=db.cursor()

table=soup.findAll('table')[6]

#print table

for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    cells = row.findAll('td')
    #For each "tr", assign each "td" to a variable.
    if len(cells) == 19:
        column1 = cells[0].find(text=True)
        column2 = cells[1].find(text=True)
        column3 = cells[2].find(text=True)
        column4 = cells[3].find(text=True)
        column5 = cells[4].find(text=True)
        column6 = cells[5].find(text=True)
        column7 = cells[6].find(text=True)
        column8 = cells[7].find(text=True)
        column9 = cells[8].find(text=True)
        column10 = cells[9].find(text=True)
        column11 = cells[10].find(text=True)
        column12 = cells[11].find(text=True)
        column13 = cells[12].find(text=True)
        column14 = cells[13].find(text=True)
        column15 = cells[14].find(text=True)
        column16 = cells[15].find(text=True)
        column17 = cells[16].find(text=True)
        column18 = cells[17].find(text=True)
        column19 = cells[18].find(text=True)
        TOTAL_AD_CALLS = column6.replace(',','')
        TOTAL_US_AD_CALLS = column7.replace(',','')
        TOTAL_NON_US_AD_CALLS = column8.replace(',','')
        TOTAL_NON_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS = column10.replace(',','')
        TOTAL_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS = column12.replace(',','')
        UNUSABLE_AD_CALLS = column13.replace(',','')
        NO_ADS_RETURNED = column14.replace(',','')
        PSAS_RETURNED = column15.replace(',','')
        ADS_RETURNED = column16.replace(',','')
        TOTAL_RETURNED = column17.replace(',','')
        TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS  = column18.replace(',','')
        Engagements = column19.replace(',','')
        NOT_US_RATE = column9.replace('%','')
        NOT_CLEAN_RATE = column11.replace('%','')
        Created = datetime.datetime.now()

print Engagements


cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO PYTHON_TEST (REPORT_TYPE, THE_DATE, PARENT_ID, SITE_ID,SITE_NAME, TOTAL_AD_CALLS, TOTAL_US_AD_CALLS, TOTAL_NON_US_AD_CALLS, NOT_US_RATE, TOTAL_NON_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS, NOT_CLEAN_RATE, TOTAL_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS, UNUSABLE_AD_CALLS, NO_ADS_RETURNED, PSAS_RETURNED, ADS_RETURNED, TOTAL_RETURNED, TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS, ENGAGEMENTS, CREATED) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, TOTAL_AD_CALLS, TOTAL_US_AD_CALLS, TOTAL_NON_US_AD_CALLS, NOT_US_RATE ,TOTAL_NON_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS, NOT_CLEAN_RATE, TOTAL_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS, UNUSABLE_AD_CALLS, NO_ADS_RETURNED, PSAS_RETURNED, ADS_RETURNED, TOTAL_RETURNED, TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS, Engagements, Created))

#cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO PYTHON_TEST (ENGAGEMENTS,434 ) VALUES (%s);", (Engagements))
db.commit()
'''
cursor.execute ("INSERT INTO PYTHON_TEST  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, TOTAL_AD_CALLS, TOTAL_US_AD_CALLS, TOTAL_NON_US_AD_CALLS, NOT_US_RATE ,TOTAL_NON_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS, NOT_CLEAN_RATE, TOTAL_CLEAN_US_AD_CALLS, UNUSABLE_AD_CALLS, NO_ADS_RETURNED, PSAS_RETURNED, ADS_RETURNED, TOTAL_RETURNED, TOTAL_IMPRESSIONS, Engagements, Created, Created))'''


# disconnect from server
db.close()
```